# How to Reorder Dates in Chronological Order in ggplot2

Tags: r

I am trying to reorder the dates on my graph into chronological order. I am pulling the dates from a CSV that has the dates formatted as DD-MM-YYYY. Currently, the graph is created with the dates placed at random.

How can I reorder the dates into chronological order?

Here is the code I am using to produce the graph:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(gym, aes(x=D1, y=B1))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, color="orange")+
  theme_linedraw()+
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("Weight (lbs)")+
  ggtitle("Weight (lbs) vs. Date")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `D1` column to date class and that should fix the plot.

```
gym$D1 <- lubridate::dmy(gym$D1)
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but only once. If I run `gym$D1 <- lubridate::(gym$D1)` a second time, I get the following error message "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number".

Comment: You mean `lubridate::dmy` right? You are supposed to run it only once on the dataset. Once the column is changed to date class no need to run it again.

Comment: Got it! This works beautifully and simply. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
gym$D1 <- as.Date(gym$D1, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```